# Display image and play audio clip in applet

Tags: java, applet

I want to display image in an applet and play audio clip. I wrote the following code but its not working. I have written code just for image but dont have any idea for audio clip. Please let me know where I am making mistake..

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
/*
<applet code="Showimage" width = 400 height = 400>
</applet>
*/
public class Showimage extends Applet
{
URL codb;
Image picture;
public void init()
{
    codb = getCodeBase();
    picture = getImage(codb, "Choti.jpg");
}
public String getAppletInfo()
{
    return "Hi...";
}
public void start() {   }
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(picture, 10, 10, this);
    showStatus(getAppletInfo());
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
/*
<applet code="Showimage" width = 400 height = 400>
</applet>
*/
public class Showimage extends Applet
{
    URL codb;
    Image picture;
    AudioClip clip;

    public void init()
    {
        picture = getImage(getCodeBase(), "../images/Beagle.jpg");

        clip  = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "sound/woof.wav");
    }

    public String getAppletInfo()
    {
        return "Hi...";
    }

    public void start() { 
        clip.play();
        showStatus(getAppletInfo());
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(picture, 10, 10, this);
    }
}
```

Would find the image & sound with this directory structure.

- images

  - Beagle.jpg
- applet

  1. sound

     - woof.wav
  2. applet.html

Comment: What does "../images/Beagle.jpg" mean in  picture = getImage(getCodeBase(), "../images/Beagle.jpg"); What is .. before/imges

Comment: `..` in an URL means 'parent directory`.  The codebase is not specified in the HTML so it defaults to the same as the document base (the `applet` directory).  We need to retrieve the image from the `images` directory which is 'beside' the `applet` directory.  See the list structure at the bottom of the post, it shows the directory/file structure that would work for the code shown.

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson Still not clear with the explanation. Do you mean that I need to store the image directory in the same folder as of applet directory? I want to display image from any directory of my local disk. Can i do this with this code?? Sorry but I am new in JAVA..

Comment: The local disk is no good.  Only a signed and trusted applet can load files from the local file-system, and then it is the local file system of the computer that the *end user* is using.  If the image & clip is to be used in a sand-boxed applet, it must be somewhere on the *same site* as the applet.

Comment: .You mean to say I need to store .class file and image directory in the same folder??

Comment: Folders are more something that relates to the local disks. `C:`, `D:` etc.  Where are you hosting the applet?  What URL?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4130/discussion-between-andrew-thompson-and-chirag-fanse)

Answer (score 1):

An `applet` class and image `"Choti.jpg"` must be in same folder.

Use `getImage(java.net.URL)` method to get an image from other location/folder and use `play(URL,string)` or `play(URL)` method to play audio clip. For more detail visit [applet tutorial.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/)

Comment: @AVD..Is there any way to display image from any other folder..?? And what about audio clip? How can I play it..